# Destination is mandatory

Tags: jms, wildfly, message-driven-bean

I got following error while deploying my ear in wildfly 8.1.0 server

**1)Error:**

```
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.InvalidPropertyException: Destination is mandatory",
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"wildfly.ear\".\"wildfly-     ejb.jar\".component.ReRattingMDB.START" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service   jboss.deployment.subunit.\"wildfly.ear\".\"wildfly-ejb.jar\".component.ReRattingMDB.START:   java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.resource.spi.InvalidPropertyException: Destination is  mandatory
```

**2)MDB CODE:**

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "ReRatting_Queue",activationConfig =
    {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="messagingType", propertyValue="javax.jms.MessageListener"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destinationType", propertyValue="javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="Destination", propertyValue="java:/queue/ReRatting_Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="ConnectionFactoryName", propertyValue="ConnectionFactory"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="MaxPoolSize", propertyValue="1"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="MaxMessages", propertyValue="1"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "true")
    })
```

**3)standard-full.xml:**

```
      <jms-queue name="ReRatting_Queue">
      <entry name="java:/queue/ReRatting_Queue"/>
      <durable>true</durable>
      </jms-queue>
```

Please help me any one why this error came and how to solve this issue in wildfly8 application server

Regards
Shankar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess the property names must start with a lower case letter. You typed 'Destination' but I'm pretty sure it must be named 'destination'.

Comment: Ok then please accept the answer to show the other users that your question has been solved. This helps a lot if someone has similar issues.